# Check for an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to check if input array is not empty. It is a droppable area. User dropes inside name and then saves it.
Here is placeholder:

```
<div class="procLeader">
<label>Leader:</label>  
<ol>
    <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

And after dropping items inside placeholder I am saving names with function:

```
var LISTOBJ3 = {
  saveList: function() {
    $(".procLeader").each(function() {
      var listCSV = [];
      $(this).find("li").each(function() {
        listCSV.push($(this).text());
      });
      var values = '' + listCSV.join(', ') + '';
      $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='procLeader[]' value='" + values + "' />");
      $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
      console.debug(listCSV);
    });
  }
}
```

So I neeed to check if input `procleader[]` is not empty. I am trying to do so by using javascript:

```
var procLeader = document.forms["myForm"]["procLeader[]"].value;
if (procLeader == null || procLeader == "" || procLeader == "Drop Here") {
    alert("Please fill Process Leader Field");
    return false;
}
```

But it keeps giving me warning even if item is dropped. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `name` is not a standard attribute of `<li>` elements.

Comment: use `class="processLeader[]` instead of `name``

Comment: If you have multiple inputs with the same name, `document.forms["myForm"][name]` will be a list, not a single element. You need to loop over them, testing if all of them are empty.

Comment: Why do people write `'' + something + ''`? What's the point of concatenating empty strings to things?

Comment: @Barmar I do not concatenate anything, I use comas for value  `value='  " + values +  "   '` and in my case it doesnt work without `+`

Comment: I'm talking about: `var values = '' + listCSV.join(', ') + '';` That's concatenating empty strings at the beginning and end.

Comment: @Barmar and I have one input only not multiple, i store all the names in one input

Comment: it's no different from `var values = listCSV.join(', ')`.

Comment: You do `$('.procLeader').each()` and append `<input name='procLeader[]'>` every time through that loop. So you'll get as many inputs as you have `.procLeader`.

Comment: @Barmar oh i see, thanks

Comment: @Barmar but I will have it only once, after hitting submit button, [here you can check what i mean](https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/146/)

Comment: @Barmar yes it will display as many times as i hit submit button, but values will be still the same.

Comment: Why do you use `.each()` if there's only one of them? BTW, why is it `projLeader` in the fiddle, but `procLeader` in the question?

Comment: @Barmar is is just as example

Comment: I don't see how to get the error in your fiddle. Where is the submit button that does the alert? Save just adds another input field, it doesn't alert anything.

Comment: @Barmar i didnt add it there

Comment: You said to check the fiddle to see what you mean about having only one input after hitting the submit button. But there's no submit button. What removes all the extra inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript equivalent of PHP's empty() method

```
function empty (mixed_var) {
// version: 909.322
// discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/empty
var key;
if (mixed_var === "" || mixed_var === 0 || mixed_var === "0" || 

mixed_var === null || mixed_var === false || mixed_var === undefined ) {
        return true;
    }
    if (typeof mixed_var == 'object') {
        for (key in mixed_var) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how you made this. Did you translate it from PHP? Do you implement it based on the PHP spec?

Comment: I didn't make it the link is in the code sample.  It's from that site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
if (procLeader === false) {...} 
// will catch the empty array.

procLeader == null
// catches null input.  

procLeader == "Drop Here"
// will catch the default input.
```